# Incorrect Value after using Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to solve $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\int_{0}^{x^2} x^2 e^{-t^2} dt}{-1+e^{-x^4}} $$ using The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (FTC).
I already know that the answer is -1,

Using FTC (correct me if I am wrong) we get:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2 e^{-x^4}}{-1+e^{-x^4}}
$$

Which has the result of - $\infty$

I can't seem to know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure about $\int_0^y e^{-t^2} dt=e^{-y^2}$, which you seem to be using.

Comment: **HINT:** Don't forget to use L'Hopital's Theorem.

Comment: @OskarLimka how am I supose to do it then? any hints?

Comment: @K.Jiang I used it to solve the last limit and I still get -infinity

Comment: Show us your work with L'Hôpital. Don't forget Leibnitz rule.

Comment: I think it may be a problem with the integral; why is $x^{2}$ part of the integrand?

Comment: When using FTC, need to differentiate $x^2$ (Chain Rule).  Also, need to use the Product Rule when differentiating the top.

Comment: Look at the first limit.  The denominator goes to zero since $e^{-x^4}\to 1$.  The numerator goes to zero since the integrand is bounded:  $e^{-t^2}\approx 1$ for $t$ very small.  Thus you can apply L'Hôpital's.

Comment: And you forgot to differentiate the bottom. By the way, I would not use L'Hospital's Rule, series are the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a $\frac{0}{0}$ limit, you can use L'Hospital's Rule. To do so, factor the numerator as $x^2 g(x)$, where $$g(x) = \int_{0}^{x^2} e^{-t^2} dt$$

You are allowed to pull the $x^2$ outside of the integrand as the integral is with respect to $t$. Use FTC (and the product rule) to calculate the derivative of the numerator when you apply L'Hospital's Rule. Then clean up the resulting mess and repeat. Eventually, you should end up with a limit of $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the fundamental theorem of calculus you should replace the integral

$$
\int_0^{x^2} e^{-t^2} dx \simeq1 \cdot x^2 = x^2
$$
becaus the mean value of $e^{-t^2}$ near $t=0$ is just 1, and the length of your interval is $x^2$, hence the limit you want is

$$
\lim_{x \to 0 } \frac{x^4}{e^{-x^4}  -1}  = -1
$$

Comment: This is still incomplete, both numerator and denominator go to zero as x goes to zero. It seems that you need l'hospital as a final step.

Comment: But if you apply it you get 0/-1 which doesn't equal -1...

Comment: Indeed it is a hint so that the OP can work out the remaining details. You will not get, but -1,  just by looking at the Taylor expansion of $e^{-x^4}$, or using L'Hospital rule.

Comment: I see now that my previous comment was a mistake. Applying L'Hospital to $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^4}{e^{-x^4}-1}$ yields -1 as you stated.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do some pre-processing of the term. It is equal to
$$
\left(\frac{e^{-x^4}-1}{x^4}\right)^{-1}·\frac{\int_0^{x^2}e^{-t^2}dt}{x^2}
$$
and thus the limit can be computed by product and quotient rule as
$$
\left(\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{-h}-1}{h}\right)^{-1}·\lim_{s\to 0}\frac{\int_0^{s}e^{-t^2}dt}{s}
$$
which are two difference quotients for the functions $f(x)=e^{-x}$ with $f'(x)=-e^{-x}$ and $g(x)=\int_0^{s}e^{-t^2}dt$ with $g'(x)=e^{-x^2}$.